# $.ajax get success data properties are undefined. Cannot access data's individual properties

Tags: json, ajax, undefined

I am trying to make an ajax call to a controller method that returns a serialized object.

The ajax get call retrieves the object well (I can log the result and all data is there) but when I try to access the individual properties I get "Undefined".

This is the line in the controller method that returns the serialized data to the ajax method.

```
  public JsonResult PopulateMonitor()
    {
        return Json(GetGameBoards(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And this is the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "/Dashboard/PopulateMonitor/",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function () {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.HomeBeer);
        });
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error, could not load gameboards");
    } 
});
```

The line:

```
 console.log(data);
```

returns:

```
  {
    "GameChannel": 1,
    "HomeTeamName": "BEARS",
    "AwayTeamName": "PACKERS",
    "HomeTeamScore": "14",
    "AwayTeamScore": "27",
    "HomeDrinkMin": 1.3,
    "HomeDrinkMax": 6,
    "AwayDrinkMin": 0.8,
    "AwayDrinkMax": 5.5,
    "Multiplier": 1,
    "HomeTeamImage": "/Images/NFLTeams/BEARS.png",
    "AwayTeamImage": "/Images/NFLTeams/PACKERS.png",
    "HomeBeer": "Coors Lite",
    "AwayBeer": "Miller Lite",
    "HomeBeerPrice": "284.50",
    "AwayBeerPrice": "283.30",
    "HomeBeerAdjustedPrice": "1.00",
    "AwayBeerAdjustedPrice": "1.00",
    "HomeBeerPreviousPrice": "283.50",
    "AwayBeerPreviousPrice": "282.30",
    "HomeTeamArrow": "/Images/Comparators/UP.png",
    "AwayTeamArrow": "/Images/Comparators/UP.png"
   }
```

but the line

```
console.log(data.HomeBeer);
```

returns:

```
undefined
```

How can i do a similar action to;

```
console.log(data.HomeBeer)
```

to return "Coors Lite"

Comment: If you look closely, I'm pretty sure that `console.log(data)` logs `[{ ... }]`. That means, `data` is an array, so `data.HomeBeer` does not exist, but `data[0].HomeBeer` does. Look again how `$.each` works, you're not using it correctly.

Comment: You are a beautiful human being! Thank you! You are correct. I completely overlooked that. I am now using `$.each(data, function (index, val) {` to iterate correctly and then accessing using `val[0].HomeBeer`.

Comment: `val.HomeBeer` should be it, unless `val` is *another* array, which I guess it isn't.